# Camera screen orientation issue Samsung galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

In my app i am trying to take a pic from camera and displaying it in the `imageview`.Everything works fine but when i took pic from samsung galaxy s3 , it changed the orientation and displays the camera activity and `onActivity` result it displayed the pic in the `imageView` but in a fraction of seconds it changed the orientation again removed the pic from `imageview`.Its very weird how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Camera intent not working with Samsung Galaxy S3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248265/camera-intent-not-working-with-samsung-galaxy-s3)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably late to answer but I think that your onCreate method is called after the orientation change thus the ImageView bitmap that you are setting is null after orientation change.

Try saving your data and variables by Overriding onSaveInstanceState(). This method is called each time the orientation changes. Save variables and values that you want to retain after orientation change.

Hope I am right and this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: But i need to support horizontal also.

Comment: SO you need to find out the camera pic captured state and then you can change to Horizontal also.

Comment: I'm not totally sure this addresses the OP's question. If you believe it does, re-read his question carefully to double-check, and then edit your answer to add some explanation as to why this is correct. It is more important to communicate the underlying logic than just the code by itself - if one grasps the logic, they'll be able to write this and similar code themselves.